# gradle-release-plugin release task on Bamboo cause infinite loop

Tags: release, bamboo, gradle-release-plugin

I use Bamboo to release builds and publish it to Nexus. It works well using maven-release-plugin, but on Gradle, using gradle-release-plugin I got infinite loop.

Right after build plan task succeded, Bamboo checks git, found 2 new commits "[Gradle Release Plugin]" created during previous release and starts again and again.

How to make Bamboo ignore these commits?

Answer (score 3):

You can configure Bamboo repository to ignore changes which match the ones created by gradle-release-plugin.

[image]

More information in the [docs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/git-289277007.html)

Answer (score 1):

I found this Atlassian issue https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-5758. Atlassian engineers just hardcoded maven-release-plugin commit messages to make Bamboo ignore it.

So all you need is to specify **preTagCommitMessage** and **newVersionCommitMesage**, masking commit messages like it's maven-release-plugin

`preTagCommitMessage = '[maven-release-plugin] prepare release '
    newVersionCommitMessage = '[maven-release-plugin] prepare for next development iteration '`

[image]